# $f$ is real only on the real axis thus $f$ has at most one zero

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be an holomorphic function on the unit disc so that $f$ is
>   real only on the real axis. Prove that $f$ has at most one zero in the
>   unit disc.

I know that it has something to do with the argument principle: $f$ can circle $(0,0)$ ay most one time, so the change in the argument is at most $2\pi$ but I don't really know how to put that into words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a closed path has to cross $\mathbb{R}$ at least twice for each time it winds around the origin. Consider the closed path around the boundary of the unit disc.