# If f is entire and f(z) is real if and only if z is real then f can have at most one zero

Tags: complex-analysis

I am only able to that zero occured only on real line.
I tried prove using contradiction. But not succeed.
Any hint will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/453386/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1044732/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2634606/42969

Comment: I do not understand why on real axis more than 1 zeros not possible.please help me

Comment: And [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265814/if-fz-is-entire-and-fz-is-real-iff-z-is-real-prove-fz-is-not-eq/) ...